# Retrieve the names of files in a folder, SSH

Tags: php, file, ftp

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the names of all files in a specific folder in my FTP.

I only have an ssh access to my ftp. (SFTP) So, ftp function for php doesn't work for me.

I want for example, retrieve all names of all files in my folder /var/www/test/.

Any ideas?

PS : Please, stop down vote, i can't ask more questions now ^^

Comment: using PHP FTP extension? or a simple FTP connection with a ftp client?

Comment: It's not an FTP access but SSH (SFTP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example taken from the manual

```
<?php
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
```

[`ftp_nlist()`](http://php.net/ftp-nlist)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php

Take a look at the above link. Should be sufficient

Comment: Just a link is a little bit too less, because the site may be down some time in the future (especially if you link to a concrete mirror `nl3`)